# App is crashing when I add fragment in main activity layout and add code of it

Tags: java, android, android-activity, navigation, fragment

I have created one app which contains bottom navigation but when I am trying to add fragment in MAin Activity Or add code about fragment switching then it will get crash.

I am adding the **activity_main.XML**, **MainActivity.main** and **Build.gradle**, **Logs** also Added

**activity_main.XML**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"

        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="selected"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"

        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**MainActivity.Main**

```
package com.androtechbuddy.collegetest;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

import java.util.Objects;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    private BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
    private NavController navController;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);
        navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.frame_layout);

        Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavigationView, navController);
    }

}
```

***Build.gradle***

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.androtechbuddy.collegeapptest"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.5'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0-alpha02'
    implementation 'com.github.smarteist:autoimageslider:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:18.0.3'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.7.0'
    implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2'



    implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.5.0'

}
```

**Logs**

```
2021-04-29 23:27:28.487 1300-1300/com.androtechbuddy.collegeapptest E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.androtechbuddy.collegeapptest, PID: 1300
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.androtechbuddy.collegeapptest/com.androtechbuddy.collegeapptest.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8 in com.androtechbuddy.collegeapptest:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #8 in com.androtechbuddy.collegeapptest:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3501)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3661)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2108)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7876)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:656)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:967)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8 in com.androtechbuddy.collegeapptest:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #8 in com.androtechbuddy.collegeapptest:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8 in com.androtechbuddy.collegeapptest:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: no start destination defined via app:startDestination for com.androtechbuddy.collegeapptest:id/mobile_navigation
        at androidx.navigation.NavGraphNavigator.navigate(NavGraphNavigator.java:61)
        at androidx.navigation.NavGraphNavigator.navigate(NavGraphNavigator.java:28)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:1066)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.onGraphCreated(NavController.java:639)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.java:592)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.java:557)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.java:539)
        at androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment.onCreate(NavHostFragment.java:248)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2684)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.create(FragmentStateManager.java:280)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1175)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1356)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.onCreateView(FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.java:109)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:135)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:356)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:335)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1071)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:999)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:963)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1125)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1086)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:684)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:536)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170)
        at com.androtechbuddy.collegeapptest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
2021-04-29 23:27:28.487 1300-1300/com.androtechbuddy.collegeapptest E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8093)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8067)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1310)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3474)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3661)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2108)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7876)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:656)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:967)
2021-04-29 23:27:28.487 943-943/? E/qdmetadata: paramType 2048 not supported
```

***Can Please Anyone tell me what's wrong with my code? And How to resolve this problem.***

Comment: can you post the logs here because that will be easy to identify your problem?

Comment: Hey, Added Logs

Comment: The error says `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: no start destination defined via app:startDestination for com.androtechbuddy.collegeapptest:id/mobile_navigation` - so do you have a start destination set on your graph? Please include your navigation graph XML file.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Hey, can you tell me How to add navigation graph XML? I didn't understand which graph you are talking about???

Comment: Your `activity_main.xml` you've included has this line: `app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation"` - so you already have a `mobile_navigation.xml` file in the `res/navigation` directory. Perhaps you should go through the [Navigation Getting Started guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started) to understand some of the code you have in your app.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Thank You So Much Brother now my problem is solved. Can you Please upvote my Question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: no start destination defined via app:startDestination for com.androtechbuddy.collegeapptest:id/mobile_navigation`.

You'll want to check your `mobile_navigation.xml` file in the `res/navigation` folder to make sure you've defined an `app:startDestination` on your `<navigation>` element with the `android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"` as per the [Designate a start destination step of the Getting Started guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started#Designate-start).